# tomcat extract multiple war files simultaneously

Tags: tomcat

I am a newbie in tomcat. I have a project that contains multiple war files (more than 15). When I deploy these many war files and start tomcat application, it extracts folders for each war file sequentially (one by one), which considerably increases the downtime and time to deploy.

I guess there would be some way which can help to extract these many war files simultaneously and thereby reduce downtime and deployment time.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `startStopThreads` on the `Host` element in `server.xml` which should do what you want.

[From the documentation :](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Common_Attributes)

> The number of threads this Host will use to start child Context elements in parallel.